# Simple analog for plotting a line from a table object in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been unable to find a simple analog for plotting a line graph from a table object in ggplot2.  Given the elegance and utility of the package, I feel I must be missing something quite obvious.  As an illustration consider a data frame with yearly observations:

```
dat<-data.frame(year=sample(c("2001":"2010"),1000, replace=T))
```

And a quick time series plot in base R:

```
plot(table(dat$year), type="l")
```

Switching to qplot, returns the error "attempt to apply a non-function":

```
qplot(table(dat$year), geom="line")
```

ggplot2 requires a data frame. Fair enough.  But this returns the same error.

```
qplot(year, data=dat, geom="line")
```

After some searching and fiddling, I abandoned `qplot`, and came up with the following approach which involves specifying a line geometry, binning the counts, and dropping final values to avoid plotting zeros.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(year) ) + geom_line(stat = "bin", binwidth=1, drop=TRUE)
```

It seems like rather a long walk around the block. And it is still not entirely satisfactory, since the bins don't align precisely with the mid-year values on the x-axis. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe still more complicated than you want, but:

```
qplot(Var1,Freq,data=as.data.frame(table(dat$year)),geom="line",group=1)
```

(the `group=1` is necessary because the Year variable (`Var1`) is returned as a factor ...)

If you didn't need it as a one-liner you could use `ytab <- as.data.frame(table(dat$year))` first to extract the table and convert it to a data frame ...

Following Brian Diggs's answer, if you're willing to construct a bit more `fortify` machinery you can condense this a bit more:

A utility function that converts a factor to numeric if possible:

```
conv2num <- function(x) {
    xn <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(x)))
    if (!all(is.na(xn))) xn else x
}
```

And a `fortify` method that turns the table into a data frame and then tries to make the columns numeric:

```
fortify.table <- function(x,...) {
    z <- as.data.frame(x)
    facs <- sapply(z,is.factor)
    z[facs] <- lapply(z[facs],conv2num)
    z
}
```

Now this works almost as you would like it to:

```
qplot(Var1,Freq,data=table(dat$year),geom="line")
```

(It would be nice/easier if there were a `table` option to preserve the numeric nature of cross-classifying factors ...)

Comment: Thanks, Ben. That works for me.  Specifying group=1 is something I completely overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Ben's answer, the "standard" approach would be to create the data frame from the table, at which point you can covert the years back into numbers.

```
ytab <- as.data.frame(table(dat$year))
ytab$Var1 <- as.numeric(as.character(ytab$Var1))
```

The either of the following will work:

```
ggplot(ytab, aes(Var1, Freq)) + geom_line()
qplot(Var1, Freq, data=ytab, geom="line")
```

[image]

The other approach is to create a `fortify` function which will transform the table into a data frame, and use that.

```
fortify.table <- as.data.frame.table
```

Then you can pass the table directly instead of a data frame. But `Var1` is now still a factor and so you need `group=1` to connect the line across years.

```
ggplot(table(dat$year), aes(Var1, Freq)) + geom_line(aes(group=1))
qplot(Var1, Freq, data=table(dat$year), geom="line", group=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I very much appreciate the thoughtful answers.  Introduced me to some important and useful approaches to ggplot2 beyond the simple case I presented.